# Merging large data set in fastest possible way

Tags: text-processing, files, csv

I have a large data set ~100 GBs having smaller csv files ~ 100,000. I wish to merge all .csv files together in the fastest possible way. Files are located in two different folders.

1. Someone suggested me to create two files having file names of the
   file from both the folders, and using the file name, iterate in the
   directory to append the output files, rather than using glob `ls *`.
   How can I achieve this using Linux. I'm fairly new to this, if
   someone can help me out, I would appreciate.
2. If there any other way, considering the data set, to achieve the
   result

Comment: What do you mean by merging? Do you just need to concatenate them, or join them by a common column, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
find /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2 -type f -name '*.csv' -exec cat {} + >/path/to/merged.csv
```

Make sure not to put the merged file in either of the input directories. :)

Comment: Isn't the `\ ` after the `+` needed?

Comment: @kos I suppose you mean `\ ` _before_ `+`.  No, it isn't needed.  `;` in `-exec {} \;` needs to be escaped because otherwise the shell would take it as a command terminator, but `+` doesn't have any special meaning to the shell and thus will be passed along to `find`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, you're right, I just memorized `\+` the first time I've  learned it, for an unknown reason

Comment: I ve used the same code as put @Icd047 , however, I'm looking for the most efficient way as I have limited memory. I

Comment: I used method similar to the above posted, and the performance was fairly good. Hence, marking it as answered.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a single (100GB-sized?) file from all of your files. In that case cat might do the trick:

```
cat foo1 foo2 bar1 bar2 > newfile
```

or in your case

```
cat folder1/* folder2/* > newfile
```

which will take all files from folder1 and folder2 and merge them (as text) into newfile. note that cat just appends the files at the end (i.e. adding lines)

This will however keep the old files and thus you'll need twice the space, so you might also treat them individually:

```
for f in folder1/* folder2/* ; do
    cat $f >> newfile && rm $f
done
```

that way each file is added and then removed.

Is that what you were searching for?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I ve done something similar. However, I'm more concerned about the performance of the query. Is it the most efficient way of solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If all the CSV files have the same structure (header), and placed in 2-levels sub-directories, you might want to use DuckDB which can handle such load (100k files / GB of data) with reasonably recent computers that have 32GB or 64GB of RAM

Here is a way to ingest all files:

```
CREATE TABLE merge AS SELECT * from read_csv_auto('*/*/*.csv');
```

a quick glance of the table generated

```
SUMMARIZE SELECT * from merge;
```

and finally, to export to a single csv file

```
COPY merge TO 'export.csv' (HEADER, DELIMITER ',');
```